# MySQL query SELECT inside IN

Tags: mysql

I'm new in SQL, have a comlpex query for me which choose only one cheapest line from each cityId to each cityId:

```
SELECT cityIdFrom, cityIdTo, MIN(fromToPrice) fromToPrice_min 
FROM pricing
WHERE cityIdFrom IN (91, 94, 95, 99)
AND cityIdTo IN (91, 94, 95, 99)
GROUP BY cityIdFrom, cityIdTo
```

So we take cheapest from 91 to 94, cheapest from 91 to 95 etc. How can I fix this query to SELECT lines for cityIdFrom 91 only when column Bull IS 1.
For example, if we have:

```
cityIdFrom - cityIdTo - fromToPrice - Bull
91, 94, 3000, 0
91, 94, 5000, 1
91, 95, 1000, 0
91, 99, 1500, 1
99, 95, 2000, 0
```

Our query will give us:

```
91, 94, 5000, 1
91, 99, 1500, 1
99, 95, 2000, 0
```

Thank for help!

Comment: `AND Bull = 1` in the WHERE clause?? I guess it's not that obvious or you'd have done it...what have I missed from your explanation?

Comment: Ok just seen your edit... how about `AND ((CityIdFrom = 91 AND Bull = 1) OR CityIdFrom <> 91)` . Does that cut it?

Comment: @ADyson I have not enough knowledge to make this Query. I dont know where to put this Bull = 1 only for first cityId (91).

Comment: See my second comment just now. I think it should allow all rows where CityIdFrom is not 91, and all rows where CityIdFrom is 91 _and_ bull = 1. I can't test it but you can...

Comment: @ADyson hey, it worked! Thank you! Was so simple, dont know how I didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was all about one line in my Query:

```
AND (CityIdFrom = 91 AND Bull = 1) OR CityIdFrom <> 91
```

Many thanks to @ADyson, he helped me so much!